# awk: comparing two files containing numbers

Tags: shell, awk

I'm using this command to compare two files and print out lines in which $1 is different:

`awk -F, 'NR==FNR {exclude[$1];next} !($1 in exclude)' old.list new.list > changes.list`

the files I'm working with have been sorted numerically with -n

old.list:

```
30606,10,57561
30607,100,26540
30611,300,35,5.068
30612,100,211,0.035
30613,200,5479,0.005
30616,100,2,15.118
30618,0,1257,0.009
30620,14,8729,0.021
```

new.list

```
30606,10,57561
30607,100,26540
30611,300,35,5.068
30612,100,211,0.035
30613,200,5479,0.005
30615,50,874,00.2
30616,100,2,15.118
30618,0,1257,0.009
30620,14,8729,0.021
30690,10,87,0.021
30800,20,97,1.021
```

Result

```
30615,50,874,00.2
30690,10,87,0.021
30800,20,97,1.021
```

I'm looking for a way to tweak my command and make awk print lines only if $1 from new.list is not only unique but also > $1 from the last line of the old.list

Expected result:

```
30690,10,87,0.021
30800,20,97,1.021
```

because 30690 and 30800 ($1) > 30620 ($1 from the last line of old.list)
in this case, 30615,50,874,00.2 would not be printed because 30615 is admitedly unique to new.list but it's also < 30620 ($1 from the last line of the old.list)

`awk -F, '{if ($1 #from new.list > $1 #from_the_last_line_of_old.list) print }'`

something like that, but I'm not sure it can be done this way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the awk you have but then pipe through `sort` to sort numeric high to low then pipe to `head` to get the first:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]; next} !($1 in seen)' old new | sort -nr | head -n1
30690,10,87,0.021
```

Or, use an the second pass to find the max in awk and an END block to print:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{seen[$1]; next} 
(!($1 in seen)) {uniq[$1]=$0; max= $1>max ? $1 : max}
END {print uniq[max]}' old new 
30690,10,87,0.021
```

---

Cup of coffee and reading you edit, just do this:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{ref=$1; next} $1>ref' old new
30690,10,87,0.021
30800,20,97,1.021
```

1. Since you are only interested in the values greater than the last line of `old` there is no need to even look at the other lines of that file;
2. Just read the full first file and grab the last $1 since it is already sorted and then compare to $1 in the new file. If `old` is not sorted or you just want to save that step, you can do:

   `FNR==NR{ref=$1>ref ? $1 : ref; next}`
3. if you need to uniquely the values in `new` you can do that as part of the sort step you are already doing:

   `sort -t, -k 1,1 -n -u new`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue is that there may be more than 1 new entry. For instance there could be: 30691,10,87,0.021, 30800,10,87,0.021
And I also want to print those

Comment: Thanks Dawg, it's working perfectly. It ends up being more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

single-pass `awk` solution :

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN { ___ = log(!(_^= FS = ",")) # set def. value to -inf
>
>       } NR==FNR ? __[___=$_] : ($_ in __)<(+___<+$_)' old.txt new.txt
> ```

```
30690,10,87,0.021
30800,20,97,1.021
```

Answer (score 0):

Since both files are sorted, this command should be more efficient than the other solutions here:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{x=$1}; $1>x{x=$1; print}' <(tail -n1 old) new
```

- It reads only one line from `old`
- It prints only lines where `new.$1` > `old[last].$1`
- It prints only lines with unique `$1`